# RestKit parsing/Object mapping from locally stored XML

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, restkit

I am downloading a zip, unzipping it, and then attempting to parse and object map data from an xml file included in the zip. I know if the XML file was not in a zip I could do something like

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://restkit.org/articles"];
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
    RKObjectRequestOperation *objectRequestOperation = [[RKObjectRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request responseDescriptors:@[ responseDescriptor ]];
```

But because I am download a zip, I have to (or at least I think I have to) use the following code

```
NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.mediafire.com/download/6tfd33xkiepx8a3/db_UI.zip"];
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:URL];
self.operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc]
                  initWithRequest:request];
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *path = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"testDownload"];
self.operation.outputStream = [NSOutputStream outputStreamToFileAtPath:path append:NO];

// Set download completion block
[self.operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject)
 {
     NSLog(@"Successfully downloaded file to %@", path);
     NSString *zipPath = path;
     NSString *destinationPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
     [SSZipArchive unzipFileAtPath:zipPath toDestination:destinationPath delegate:self];

 } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error)
 {
     // NSLog(@"error: %@",  operation.responseString);
 }];


// Start download operation
[self.operation start];
[RKMIMETypeSerialization registerClass:[RKXMLReaderSerialization class] forMIMEType:@"application/xml"];
```

So in this case, how can I use `RKObjectMapping`. Or is there an alternative?.......

Comment: I know I should not be setting self as delegate in the unzipFileAtPath call in the setCompletionBlockWithSuccess.. I will attempt to fix that

Answer (score 0):

This is from Rest-Kit docs, This parsing JSON object if you can change the MIME Type you can do with XML and what ever

You can find it here: [Rest-Kit docs](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Object-mapping)

```
NSString* JSONString = @"{ \"name\": \"The name\", \"number\": 12345}";
NSString* MIMEType = @"application/json";
NSError* error = nil;
id<RKParser> parser = [[RKParserRegistry sharedRegistry] parserForMIMEType:MIMEType];
id parsedData = [parser objectFromString:JSONString error:&error];
if (parsedData == nil && error) {
    // Parser error...
}


RKObjectMappingProvider* mappingProvider = [RKObjectManager sharedManager].mappingProvider;
RKObjectMapper* mapper = [RKObjectMapper mapperWithObject:parsedData mappingProvider:mappingProvider];
RKObjectMappingResult* result = [mapper performMapping];
if (result) {
    // Yay! Mapping finished successfully
}
```

Comment: This works! How does this change if I want to map to core data objects?